# Implementing drop down box in perl cgi for a value selected from database

Tags: perl, cgi

I am writing a cgi script to show a form which displays database results for a given id and also allowing the user to make changes and submit.

Eg. `select * from insp_gang where id = 1;`

The form has few text fields which shows the results from the above table.
Now i have to implement a drop down box for a column s1_q1 from the select query.
It can have 3 values. (Full,Part,No)

By default the drop down should show the current value returned by the query for this id.
At the same time, the user might be able to change it.

How do I do this?

I have the below code inside html block in my cgi script. `$job->{s1_q2}` is the variable that has the value from the database.

```
<tr><td><b> s1_q2 </b></td><td>
<select name="s1_q2">
  <option value="Full">Full</option>
  <option value="Part">Part</option>
  <option value="No">No</option>
  <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
</select>
</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach would be to create your options in a loop, and to check against the current value on each iteration of the loop.

```
my @values = qw[Full Part No N/A];

foreach my $value (@values) {
  print qq[  <option value="$value"];
  print ' selected' if $value eq $job->{s1_q2};
  print qq[">$value</option>\n";
}
```

But this kind of logic should be implemented using a templating engine.